# C# Linq Column name as two words (Last year) or as number with leading zero (01)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

From the stored procedure I get data with column names like `Last year` and `01`, `02`, `03` ... In the first case column name is consisted of two words and in other cases column names are numbers with leading zero. I know that designer of this stored procedure did something stupid, but ***I can't change stored procedure.***
My goal is to group data by some colum and then sum it by these strange  column names, but VS2017 didn't like it. I did following:

```
var list = (from r in dataFromSP
    group r by new { r.TicketTypeName, r.PaymentMonth } into grp
    select new
    {
        grp.Key.TicketTypeName,
        grp.Key.PaymentMonth,
        LastYear = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.Last year),
        M01 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.01),
        M02 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.02),
        M03 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.03),
        M04 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.04),
        M05 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.05),
        M06 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.06),
        M07 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.07),
        M08 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.08),
        M09 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.09),
        M10 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.10),
        M11 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.11),
        M12 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.12)
}).ToList<dynamic>();
```

I don't know how to use LINQ with these strange column names. I tried with [],

```
LastYear = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.[Last year]),
M01 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t.[01]),
```

and with "",

```
LastYear = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t."Last year"),
M01 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)t."01"),
```

but with no luck. Is it possible to use these strange column names in LINQ, and is there any idea how to resolve this strange situation?

Comment: What about t["Last year"] ?

Comment: I have also tried t.["Last year"] but with no luck.

Comment: You should inspect the t variables to see what properties are assigned to it. Maybe it ignores the " year" part and it's just t.Last ?

Comment: I have tried that, but it is not ignoring " year". Propertiy is "Last year"

Comment: Onyx, thank you for your help. I have resolved this issue with your suggestion and dictionary. I will post my answer bellow you can see what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue. Onyx helped me to point me in a right direction, so thank you Onyx.

This is what helped me:

```
var list = (from r in dataFromSP
    group r by new { r.TicketTypeName, r.PaymentMonth } into grp
    select new
    {
        grp.Key.TicketTypeName,
        grp.Key.PaymentMonth,
        LastYear = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["Last year"]),
        M01 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["01"]),
        M02 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["02"]),
        M03 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["03"]),
        M04 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["04"]),
        M05 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["05"]),
        M06 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["06"]),
        M07 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["07"]),
        M08 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["08"]),
        M09 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["09"]),
        M10 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["10"]),
        M11 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["11"]),
        M12 = grp.Sum(t => (decimal?)((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["12"]),
}).ToList<dynamic>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a mapping class and put your peculiar column names in a Column attribute like below. Then you'll be able to use field names without problems.

```
[Table(Name="TableNumbers")]
public class Numbers
{
    [Column(Name="Last year")]
    public int LastYear;

    [Column(Name="01")]
    public int First;
}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386983(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I will try your solution and will let you know what are the results. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: any success with it?

Comment: Not yet. I'm using stored procedure not table so I'm messed around declaring class for it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate the effort you invested in this problem. I have found the solution for it without the need to create a new class. I have combined answer from Onyx Caldin with expando to dictionary conversion. I get data as List<dynamic>. Besides the problem with col. names, I had issue with expando and indexing. I resloved the name issue with suggestion from Onyx Caldin "t["Last year"]" and indexing issue with ((IDictionary<String, Object>)t)["Last year"]). That resolved issue and now I get sums.